# Performing multiple operations simultaneously on repo

Tags: git, gerrit, repository, git-repo

We are using Google's [git-repo tool](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) for our projects. Our workflow is we make changes , merge it to remote and push tags.

My question is, is there any problem if I perform ***multiple operations*** at the same time on the same same `repo/codeline/tree`? Like suppose if I am pushing tags to remote, is there any problem if I start `repo sync`?

Or while pushing tags if I start to `cherry-pick` some new changes?

Comment: please be more specific, how is repo accessed by the client?

Comment: I am talking about repo tool. Google's repo tool which is used for software configuration management. Repo works on top of git. What do you mean by "how repo accessed by the client?" ??

Comment: This is the [Google git-repo tool](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) that the original poster was referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repo just runs git operations under the covers, so you shouldn't run into situations where the data in the individual projects is corrupted.  However, if repo tries to run a git operation on a single project while another instance of repo (or git) is running git operations on that same project, the second one will fail because it can't lock the repository.  This could result in half of your projects getting updated and the other half being left behind or something similar.

I'd recommend not using two instances of repo on the same sandbox for this reason.